# How to distinguish if code in string is a piece of JS or CSS code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I receive strings of code via simple POST requests, i am looking for a clever way (without having to run the script itself) to distinguish if it's a javascript script or css script, or at least to be quite sure (i'd say 55% possibility it is one of).

These are not files these are strings, so i don't have any information about the code in the string, no file, no file ext, no headers...

Do  you have any advice/resource?

thanks a lot.

Comment: You can run [css-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-validator) and [jshint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint) on it. And check which one succeeds.

Comment: maybe you can search the strings for pure css code and elements, and that way you will know that is clearly CSS and not javascript. lets say that "line-through" is CSS and Not JS. and so on...

Comment: @t.niese what if script is broken? i must accept them too

Comment: @GrowingDev that would be huge, because i don't know if any rule is present or not

Comment: well, maybe you can search for ":" and ";", which is for CSS.
The template for a CSS **{** something **:** something **;**  **}** and js must contain classes, vars and other as you know. search for the template of css that i have written here, if it's that, the you know its CSS, if not, you will know its something else.
@sbaaaang

Comment: @GrowingDev not bulletproof i guess :(

Comment: @sbaaaang well, it's kinda on the fly, and im on the train right now(lol), from the phone, but I'm sure this will catch the css. of course you can do better with more inspection. i don't even know how the strings look like.

Comment: If you need to accept broken css and js, then there is not bulletproof way to test it. You can use or create a error tolorant js ([esprima](http://esprima.org/)) and css parser, and count the errors and weight it.

Comment: @GrowingDev That won't work because JavaScript uses that syntax for objects. `{ propertyname: value }`

Comment: @Makaze in the CSS you will not use(for the most part the "(" or ")".) as i said and others as well, he have to consider the broken code.

Comment: Perhaps some statistical method by counting the number of each kind of non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @GrowingDev `var x = 345; var c = 202992;` just for example of course there is no safe method, i would like to go on to try to find the best solution, maybe some regexp pattern based on most used var, function, etc ?

Comment: @sbaaaang if that variable will not define a css element, you could add it to the CSS strings. but you can see its very very misguiding. need to see the stream of strings in order to create a proper function for this.

Comment: I dunno. CSS has variables too. `var(--something)` and as for brackets. background uses `url()`. and there is `calc()` which may use operators. You also have `[class$=somethin]`

Comment: yep :(
..................... MAYBE the best way is to look for some of the most common css rules mmm

Comment: I voted this as too broad, both because it has spawned a lengthy discussion in comments that won't be useful to the final answer, and for the fact that multiple suggestions in the comments have lead to more and more roadblocks to the final solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this has to work with broken code too, I think your best chance is to search for "typical CSS" and "typical JS" stuff, and compare how much speaks for JS and how much for CSS.

Typical for JS are it's [reserved words](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp), and it's [operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Typical for CSS is the structure: [`,` seperated selectors] { [ `;` seperated key-value pairs] }

First a few utilities that triy to evaluate how much of a passed string is part of a particular language. (very basic approach, therefore should also work with broken code)

```
//returns **kind of** a percentage of how much of the string has been identified as JS/CSS
function evaluateCode(pattern, commentPattern, correctionalFactor){
    correctionalFactor = +correctionalFactor || 1;
    return function(string){
        //removing comments and compacting whitespace.
        //this avoids false hits, and provides a better estimation of how much significant text/code we have (to compute the percentage)
        var t = string.replace(commentPattern || "", "").replace(/\s+/, " ");

        return correctionalFactor * (t.match(pattern) || []).reduce(sumLengths, 0) / t.length;
    }
}
var sumLengths = (acc, match) => acc + match.length;

var evaluateJS = evaluateCode(
    /\b(?:function|return|arguments|this|var|const|let|typeof|instanceof|Array|Object)\b|[+\-*/<>&|=]+|[()\[\]\{\}]/g, 
    /\/\*[\s\S]*\*\/|\/\/[^\n]*/g,
    1.5
);

var evaluateCSS = evaluateCode(
    /[a-z0-9\.#:\[\]=,\s-]+\{(?:\s*[a-z-]+\s*:[^;]+;?)*\s*\}/gi,
    /\/\*[\s\S]*\*\//g
);
```

And the usage:

```
var jsRatio = evaluateJS(string), 
    cssRatio = evaluateCSS(string);

//If there's less than 10% difference between the two estimations, I'd call it "unclear"
if(Math.abs(jsRatio - cssRatio) < .1){
    console.log("result is ambigious, but I tend more towards");
}
console.log("%s (probabilities: css %f%, js %f%)", cssRatio > jsRatio? "css": "js", cssRatio, jsRatio);
```

I use an estimated/guessed "correctional factor" of 1.5 on evaluateJS, because the regex matches only a part of the code,
whereas the css-regex matches almost everything.

This factor only matters when the results are ambigious, usually there should be a huge gap between the two ratios.

**Edit:** another (probably better) regex to search for CSS:

```js
/[a-z0-9\-]+\s*:[^;{}]+[;}]|(?:[#.]?[a-z]+(?:[#.:\s][a-z0-9-_]+)*\s*[,{])/gi
```

this is looking only for key-value pairs and "typical" selectors, containing ids and classes, rather than the whole structure, wich should be benefitial, if css-structure is broken or too complex for the fairly simple regex.

Answer (score 0):

You might enclose the returned string in a block that prevents it from being executed (if it's JavaScript) and see if it can be parsed.

```
function isJavaScript(str)
{
    try
    {
        Function('function(){' + str + '}');
        return true; // Looks like valid JS
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        // no valid JavaScript, may be CSS
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't think this is 100% foolproof, but it may work for your purpose.

Comment: The OP says it has also to work with broken code.

Comment: yes it could be a broken line of js for example :( plus i would like to avoid evaling

Comment: @sbaaaang As already said, this will only try to parse the input - not evaluate it. But sure, it won't recognize malformed or broken JavaScript.